# Manipulate Windows audio mixer with NAudio in C#

Tags: c#, naudio

I want to write a program where I can manipulate the whole windows audio mixer using the NAudio dll. For example I want to change the volume balance of the system.

I am searching for one week. I found the WINMM.DLL but it does not work for me under Windows 7. Today I found on codeproject [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18520/Vista-Core-Audio-API-Master-Volume-Control) this article. But here the problem is I can only set the master volume. Now my question is, is it possible to manipulate the system mixer with NAudio?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_? Show your effort first! Please read [FAQ] and [ask]